# Php session isn't working in chrome of mobile

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I've a site built on codeigniter, everything working super fine the problem is, session is not initiating only in chrome of mobile, rest browsers working even in incognito mode also working. Don't know why session is not working in google chrome of mobile.! please help

I tried changing the php version, applied ssl certifications, disallowed and allowed cookied.

Comment: Did you used $autoload['libraries'] = array( 'session'); in autoload.php in config folder

Comment: Yes i used this like :
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','pagination','imagethumb','form_validation','email');

Comment: Fine. How you checking session is not working? You should provide your code in your question so people can see where is the problem.

Comment: $sessionArray= array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
               ); 
$this->session->set_userdata($sessionArray);


Simply initiating session; all browsers working even google too, but not in mobile chrome not letting session to initiate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its an issue related to timezone
Can you please check with following alternative options

Increase session expiration

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 8600;
```

If above one will not work then you can apply this trick

```
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
```

If still issue persists you can check with below mentioned trick

```
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: I tried your all 3 tricks but no luck, nothing worked for me !

Comment: Can you please check with updated chrome or in another machine, then check once

Comment: Ruhabh brother my code is working in every browser, when i logged in using mobile chrome, session is not initiating just in google chrome otherwise nothing a problem.

Comment: Yes Saim, that's why I am asking for updated chrome or in another device, if we debug like this then only we could able to find correct pattern of issue